# Nifi service going down every day

Tags: java, apache-nifi, hadoop2

I have install open source hadoop cluster and with Nifi. when i check status of sevice every day  morning : status as below.

```
INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is running at PID 23164
```

but is not responding to ping requests

After restarting service : status as below: it will work fine for the day.

```
INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port YYYY, PID=XXXX
```

```
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-101] o.a.n.p.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand ExecuteStreamCommand[id=df74862b-9744-319b-a478-34a0a4aee5b4] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/nifi/TriggerNifi/Scriptfile": error=13, Permission denied: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/nifi/TriggerNifi/Scriptfile": error=13, Permission denied
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/nifi/TriggerNifi/ScriptFile": error=13, Permission denied
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand.onTrigger(ExecuteStreamCommand.java:367)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/nifi/TriggerNifi/scriptfile": error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand.onTrigger(ExecuteStreamCommand.java:364)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
```

Comment: After restart  nifi service up and running for a day and again next i have to restart make it up
looking for permant fix why its not working service . service is running but not responding to ping, unable to access webUI.

Comment: Please use formatting to make your question easier to read (code blocks for the logs lines). The stack trace in your question is a permission denied on a local script that you are calling from ExecuteStreamCommand, you need to give the nifi user execute permissions on the file at `/data/nifi/TriggerNifi/Scriptfile`. But this is unrelated to NiFi being down. What version of nifi? Is the NiFi process alive `ps aux | grep nifi`? is the port listening `ss -anp | grep 8443`? Are there any other errors in the nifi logs?

Comment: @Sdairs Yes /data/nifi/TriggerNifi/Scriptfile file has full permission
yes i can see the process running and port
My question here when i restart it will start with new port  no. Is this is the reason service going down after 24 hours. i do t see any error in log file.

Comment: It will always use the same port after a restart. What do you mean by 'goes down'? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be related to the ExecuteStreamCommand executing against the /data/nifi/TriggerNifi/scriptfile, which it lacks permissions to run. If you ran a chmod 777 data/nifi/TriggerNifi/scriptfile and tried again, would the NiFi processor work?